# Need help understanding this algorithm for a robust estimator for Geom. dist

Tags: outliers, robust, estimators, geometric-distribution

I am trying to figure out a way to estimate the parameter for a Geometric distribution, using a random sample that is influenced by outliers. Searching through previous questions/answers, I saw this: [Robust estimation of a geometric random variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27448/robust-estimation-of-a-geometric-random-variable)

My question relates to "**Method 1**" in the accepted answer. The answer provides this algorithm (which seems to work well when I use it):

```
func.rob <- function(x, a) {
  1 - (sum(x>=a & x<(2*a)) / sum(x<a))^(1/a)
}
```

However, I do not understand the derivation. The explanation given is:

> Method 1 is based on the fact that $\text{p}(x+1|p)/\text{p}(x|p) =
> > 1-p$.  We can extend this to:
>
> $\frac{\sum_{i=0}^a \text{p}(i|p)}{\sum_{i=a+1}^{2a}\text{p}(i|p)} = (1-p)^a$

However, that doesn't appear to be true. Take this example:

```
> p = 0.02
> a = 10
> itop = seq(0,a, 1)       # Values for numerator
> ibot = seq(a+1, 2*a, 1)  # Values for denominator
> sum(dgeom(itop, p))/sum(dgeom(ibot, p))
 1.360423
> (1-p)^a
 0.8170728
```

I tried working backwards (from the algorithm, which *does* seem to work, to the equation) but I can't seem to make sense of it.

Any help would be appreciated!

[Note: I would ask this in the comments, but it won't let me. Hopefully this is okay.]